# Table goes to the next page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Table Test}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\hskip 0.5 cm \begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$D$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} \\ \cline{2-3}
$D$ & $\frac{6}{15}$ & $\frac{4}{15}$  \\ \cline{2-3}
$R$ & $\frac{4}{15}$ & $\frac{1}{15}$   \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$D$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} \\ \cline{2-3}
$D$ & $\frac{1}{15}$ & $\frac{4}{15}$  \\ \cline{2-3}
$R$ & $\frac{4}{15}$ & $\frac{6}{15}$   \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabularx}\vskip 0.5cm

$\omega_1$ \hskip 3cm $\omega_2$
\vskip .7cm
\captionof{table}{Blabla}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have an impression that float can solve this problem. But I thought it is used with table environment which I am not using. Thank you for your help!

Comment: a `table` environment is how you specify a float. That allows latex to adjust the position to avoid bad space at page breaks. If you choose not to allow floating you need to adjust the position by hand _after_ you have written the surrounding text so it  appears at a good place.

Comment: never do `\begin{tabularx}{100pt}{c|c|c|}` a `tabularx` must always have at least one `X` column, but here just use a standard `tabular` you should not use `tabularx` for such a table.

Comment: It is not a clean solution but with the placeins package you can define a float barrier that tells LaTeX to print the floats.

Answer (score 1):

Your table in `center` environment stay on page where are inserted if there is sufficient space for it. If it is not, than it is pushed to the next page but left empty space on page before.

This space, as explained @David Carlisle in his comments, can be filled by text after table inserting point, if you use `table` float environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Table Test}
\author{Me}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{solid},
                 vline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{solid},
                    colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, mode=math]}}
                }
    & D   &   R                     \\ 
D & \frac{6}{15} & \frac{4}{15}    \\ 
R & \frac{4}{15} & \frac{1}{15}     \\  
    \end{tblr}

\medskip
    \begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{solid},
                 vline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{solid},
                    colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, mode=math]}}
                }
    & D   &   R                     \\
D & \frac{6}{15} & \frac{4}{15}    \\
R & \frac{4}{15} & \frac{1}{15}     \\
    \end{tblr}

$\omega_1$ \hspace{3cm} $\omega_2$
\caption{Blabla}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For your table I suggest to use `tabularray` package. Using it, table is nicer (cells contents doesn't touch horizontal lines) and code is a bit shorter and clearer.

[image]